# Multiply array indices with numbers

Tags: numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

is there any short numpy command for the following operation in the for loops?

```
import numpy as np


a= np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0])
b= np.array([10.0,20.0,30.0])
c= np.array([100.0,200.0,300.0,900.0])
y=np.linspace(0,2,50)
m=np.array([0.2,0.1,0.3])

A,C,B,Y = np.meshgrid(a,c,b,y,indexing="ij")

print Y

for i in range(0,len(a)):
  for j in range(0,len(c)):
    for k in range(0,len(b)):
      Y[i][j][k]=Y[i][j][k]*m[k]


print "--------"
print Y
```

Abstractly I have $Y_{ijkl}$ and I want to multiply $Y_{ij0l}$ with $m_0$ and $Y_{ij1l}$ with $m_1$ and so on...

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the loop, you just need `einsum` here.

```
np.einsum('ijkl,k->ijkl', Y, m)
```

Or just broadcasted multiplication:

```
Y * m[:, None]
```

---

However, if you don't want to create the meshgrid in the first place, you can broadcast `Y` first, to make this more memory efficient.

```
np.einsum(
    "ijkl,k->ijkl",
    np.broadcast_to(y, a.shape + c.shape + b.shape + y.shape),
    m,
)
```

or:

```
np.broadcast_to(y, a.shape + c.shape + b.shape + y.shape) * m[:, None]
```

If you need A, C, B as well, you can continue with your current approach.

---

***Performance***

```
In [44]: %%timeit
    ...: np.einsum(
    ...:     "ijkl,k->ijkl",
    ...:     np.broadcast_to(y, (a.shape[0], c.shape[0], b.shape[0], y.shape[0])),
    ...:     m,
    ...: )
    ...:
21.1 µs ± 121 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [45]: %%timeit
    ...: A,C,B,Y = np.meshgrid(a,c,b,y,indexing="ij")
    ...: for i in range(0,len(a)):
    ...:   for j in range(0,len(c)):
    ...:     for k in range(0,len(b)):
    ...:       Y[i][j][k]=Y[i][j][k]*m[k]
    ...:
420 µs ± 1.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Nice! This is awesome ! This makes life easier ;)